# Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content [Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]

Tags: php, composer, bower

При попытке добавить библиотеку **symfony/var-dumper** composer долго помещает пакеты с **bower-asset**, а затем выдает эту ошибку - `[Composer\Repository\InvalidRepositoryException]                                                                                                No valid bower.json was found in any branch or tag of https://github.com/pammacdotnet/bootstrap-slider.git, could not load a package from it.`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл решения, сам composer говорит что может решить данную проблему "Только апдейтни меня", но запускать update по всем пакетам, немного глупо так как есть вероятность что новая версия приведет к проблемам роботы сайта, по этому стоит обновить только тот пакет в котором используется библиотека вызывающая проблему. В моём случае это **dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset** и вот коммент который помог с решением https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset/issues/133#issuecomment-337179853